# read csv file where value contain comma in AWS athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Hi Currently I have created a table schema in AWS Athena as follow

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS axlargetable.AEGIntJnlActivityLogStaging (
  `clientcomputername` string,
  `intjnltblrecid` bigint,
  `processingstate` string,
  `sessionid` int,
  `sessionlogindatetime` string,
  `sessionlogindatetimetzid` bigint,
  `recidoriginal` bigint,
  `modifieddatetime` string,
  `modifiedby` string,
  `createddatetime` string,
  `createdby` string,
  `dataareaid` string,
  `recversion` int,
  `partition` bigint,
  `recid` bigint 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   ) 
LOCATION 's3://ax-large-table/AEGIntJnlActivityLogStaging/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

But one of the filed (processingstate) value contain comma as "Europe, Middle East, & Africa" which displace columns order.

So what would be the best way to read this file. Thanks

Comment: Could you please show a sample of an input line? Specifically, we need to see whether the string fields in quotes. If they are quoted, then it will read the entire string as one field.

Comment: try using regEx serde. It might be doable. can you please share some sample records?

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your advice and you are right as my values are quoted it should be display correctly. but I figure it out the problem is next column however I dont know why when athen show error message it point to column number previous one. The problem was column 3 instead of column 2. which I have resolve now.

Answer (score 1):

When I removed this part

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'separatorChar' = ',',
'quoteChar' = '\"',
'escapeChar' = '\\'
)
```

I was able to read quoted text with commas in it

Answer (score 0):

As workaround - look at aws glue project.

Instead of creating table via `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`:

1. invoke [get-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/get-table.html) for your table
2. Then make json for [create-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-table.html)
3. Merge the following `StorageDescriptor` part:

   {
      "StorageDescriptor": {
        "SerdeInfo": {
          "SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"
          ...
        }
      ...
    }
4. perform create via aws cli. You will get this table in aws glue and athena be able to select correct columns.

**Notes**

1. If your table already defined `OpenCSVSerde` - they may be fixed this issue and you can simple recreate this table.
2. I do not have much knoledge about athena, but in aws glue you can delete or create table without any data loss
3. Before adding this table via [create-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-table.html) you have to check first how glue or/and athena hadles table duplicates

Answer (score -1):

This is a common messy CSV file situation where certain values contain commas.  The solution in Athena for this is to use SERDEPROPERTIES as described in the AWS doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html [the url may change so just search for 'OpenCSVSerDe for Processing']

Following is a basic create table example provided. Based on your data you would have to ensure that the data type is specified correctly (eg string)

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1 (
f1 string,
s2 string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\")
LOCATION 's3://user-test-region/dataset/test1/'